# React Redux Router Component Has Empty State

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am writing an react website that has a master-detail feel to it. I make server calls to populate my master component. When a user clicks an item on the master component, it uses React Router to navigate to a detail view. However, my state is no longer populated. Instead it appears I'm getting my initial state in this new component.

As far as I know, I'm using the latest on all the libraries.

**index.js**

```
const store = storeFactory( initialState );
const myHistory = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                  <Router history={ myHistory }>
                    <div>
                      <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
                      <Route exact path='/contrib' component={Contributions} />
                      <Route exact path='/story/:id' component={FullStory} />
                    </div>
                  </Router>                 
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Story.jsx (a child of App)**

```
 <div className="faux-row">
        <Link className="invisible-link" to={`/story/${this.props.story.id}`}>
          <div className="story">
            <div className="story-header">
```

**FullStory.jsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {
  console.log(state);     
  return {
    stories: state.story_groups
  }
}
```

story_groups as shown here is empty. How do I keep the state?

EDIT:

I am using redux-sage for middleware to call the server. The dispatch is coming out of ComponentWillMount() in the App component.

Comment: What moment do you set your `story_groups` to Redux store?

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Try using DevTools to see what actions are being called on your store. It is possible you have an reducer that is removing the data from your store either based on an action or perhaps in the "default" clause of a switch statement.